# Trying to get proguard to work but it always fails

Tags: android, proguard

Please don't close this as a duplicate!

I have tried upgrading to proguard 4.11

I have tried adding my the libraries I use and the libraries the libraries i use use (does that make sense :O)

I have tried adding `-keep class com.google.**` and keeping other classes

I have tried `-dontwarn fi.foyt.*`

Here are the related files:

proguard-project.txt

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars libs/crashlytics.jar
-libraryjars libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar
-libraryjars other/easyfoursquare4android/easyFoursquare4Android/bin/easyfousquareactivity.jar
-libraryjars other/foursquare-android-oauth/foursquare-oauth-library/bin/foursquare-oauth-library.jar
-libraryjars other/easyfoursquare4android/easyFoursquare4Android/libs/foursquare-api-1.0.2.jar
-libraryjars other/easyfoursquare4android/easyFoursquare4Android/libs/gson-2.2.1.jar
#-keep class com.google.** { *; }
#-keep class fi.foyt.foursquare.** { *; }
#-keep class javax.** { *; }
#-keep class org.** { *; }
#-dontwarn fi.foyt.*
#-keep class fi.foyt.**
#-keep public class android.content.Context
#-keep public interface fi.foyt.**
#-keep public class fi.foyt.**

#-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
#-keep class java.lang.reflect.**

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=other/foursquare-android-oauth/foursquare-oauth-library
android.library.reference.2=other/easyfoursquare4android/easyFoursquare4Android
```

Related console log: ([click me for full log](https://gist.github.com/Shereef/22b5c9bc2459bf03e727))

```
[2014-03-26 01:25:30 - MyAppName] Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext]
[2014-03-26 01:25:30 - MyAppName] Reading library jar [/Users/shereef/android-sdks/platforms/android-19/android.jar]
[2014-03-26 01:25:31 - MyAppName] Note: there were 1486 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-03-26 01:25:31 - MyAppName] Initializing...
[2014-03-26 01:25:31 - MyAppName]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:31 - MyAppName] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
[2014-03-26 01:25:31 - MyAppName] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Note: com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]       You should check your configuration for typos.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: there were 35 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:369)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:483)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Note: there were 1486 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions$Builder
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.api.io.GAEIOHandler: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: fi.foyt.foursquare.example.AuthenticationExample: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] Warning: there were 35 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:369)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - MyAppName]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:483)
[2014-03-26 01:25:32 - EasyFousquareActivity] Using default Build Tools revision 19.0.3
```

Check my `proguard-project.txt` I have commented the lines I have tried but didn't make sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some classes like `com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod` are missing from your libraries. Apparently, your application doesn't use them anyway, so you can tell ProGuard it's okay. For instance:

```
-dontwarn fi.foyt.foursquare.**

-dontnote libcore.icu.ICU
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).

Furthermore, you shouldn't specify `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options in your configuration file. The Ant/Eclipse/Gradle build process already automatically specifies all the necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you, based on the contents of your project.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Note: duplicate definition of program/library class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test this when I am home and vote up / select correct answer